# How to compare values from 2 Forms in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have one form which has 20 questions.Questions are called from table that I made.Here is the code:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim txtbox(19) As TextBox
dim strUsedQuestions as string :strUsedQuestions =",0,"
dim rndNum as integer 

For a = 1 To 20
    Do while instr( 1,   strUsedQuestions, "," & rndNum & ",") > 0 then ' 
       rndNum = Int((20 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
   Loop

   Controls("Txtbox" & a).Value = DLookup("Question", "questions_and_answers", "[questions_and_answers]![questionID]=" & rndNum )
   strUsedQuestions = strUsedQuestions  & rndNum & ","
Next a
```

The code is randomly calling 20 different questions from table(there are 30 questions in table),and now I want to split those 20 questions and make another form so there is 1 Form with 10 questions and 2 Form with 10 questions but ofcourse questions cant be the same ,any thoughts how can I do that?ty

Comment: NOT IN and IN will help  SQL wise, so "select questions where quenstionid in (1,2,3,5)" and "select questions where quenstionid not in (1,2,3,5)"

Comment: keep a temporary table or collection of items you have selected for form 1.  reroll is one of those comes up or better ret exclude them from the drawing pool when selecting items for form 2